# Must declare the scalar variable in my procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Im trying to get return form below store procedure but this is not giving me value 
can you please say what i am doing mistake in my procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CALCWEIGHT1 
@EQUATION varchar(255),
@VOLUME decimal(10,2) 
AS
BEGIN
  declare @SQL varchar(max);
  declare @WEIGHT decimal(10,2); 
 IF(@EQUATION = '') or(@EQUATION is null)  
   BEGIN
         set @EQUATION =' SELECT @WEIGHT = (('+Convert(varchar(10),@VOLUME)+' / 1728.0 * 8.907 *100.0) / 100.0)'

   END
 else  
  BEGIN
        set @SQL='SELECT @EQUATION= REPLACE('''+@EQUATION+''', ''VOLUME'', '''+Convert(varchar(10),@VOLUME)+''')'      
        exec @SQL   

    set @EQUATION='SELECT @WEIGHT= '+@EQUATION+' ' 
 END 

 execute (@EQUATION) 

END
```

for check i am execute with this value 
    EXEC CALCWEIGHT1 '',789

Thanks For your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just assigning variables. You don't really select anything.
Remove your use of `@Weight`.

Comment: Good luck with the rest of your project :-)